# <optgroup> with JSON on $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, optgroup

I’m trying to parse the JSON file in such way that the `subsectors` of JSON are shown in an `<optgroup label="">` (don’t want them to be selectable).

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "sectors": [
    {
      "title": "Business, Finance & Technology",
      "subsectors": [
        {
          "title": "Finance and insurance",
          "industries": [
            {"name": "Retail banking"},
            {"name": "Insurance"},
            {"name": "Investment banking"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "Business Services",
          "industries": [
            {"name": "Accounting & Audit"},
            {"name": "Recruitment"},
            {"name": "Legal services"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
// extra code omitted for brevity
```

And I populate the `<select>` options with this:

```
// populate <select> with available choices
$.getJSON('models/industries.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.sectors, function (i, sector) {
        $.each(sector.subsectors, function (i, subsector) {
            $('<option />').html('#' + subsector.title).appendTo('.js-industries-select');

            $.each(subsector.industries, function (i, industry) {
                $('<option />').html(industry.name).appendTo('.js-industries-select');
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Then I call the Chosen plugin to change the `<select>` into a dynamic input. You can see which elements I want as `label` being marked with `#`.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/qaczD/

I basically need to create an `<optgroup>` before the last `$.each`, assign the `label=""` as `subsector.title` and then populate that group with the choices. Once the last `$.each` has finished, close the ` somehow and start a new one.

Any ideas?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LH38A/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thisone:
http://jsfiddle.net/qaczD/2/

```
// populate <select> with available choices
$.getJSON('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48552248/websites/timewasted/new/industries.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.sectors, function (i, sector) {
        $.each(sector.subsectors, function (i, subsector) {

             var optGroup=$('<optgroup />').attr('label','#' + subsector.title).appendTo('.js-industries-select');
            $.each(subsector.industries, function (i, industry) {
                // if (industry.name.search(regex) != -1) {
                    $(optGroup).append( $('<option />').html(industry.name));
                // }
            })
        });
    });
    console.log('yes');
});

// call chosen plugin that prettifies the Industry options
setTimeout(function() {$(".js-industries-select").chosen({
  placeholder_text_multiple: 'e.g. Retail banking…'
});}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

[The solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Y36ET/)

```
 $.each(sector.subsectors, function (i, subsector) {
        var group = $('<optgroup />').attr('label','#' + subsector.title).appendTo('.js-industries-select');

        $.each(subsector.industries, function (i, industry) {
            $('<option />').html(industry.name).appendTo(group);
        })
    });
```